# Relationship between the size of the object and the distance to the camera

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I need to know if there is any way to detect circular objects with known actual size and image of known depth at different distance from the camera .

Or what is the same thing I need to know if there is a relationship between the size of the object and the distance to the camera.

For example a circle 1 inch in diameter is smaller than 5 meters from the camera, but the same object at 1 meter from the camera image obtained of the object is greater , that is the relationship I need.

Greetings .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the solution in [OpenCV: How-to calculate distance between camera and object using image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038002/opencv-how-to-calculate-distance-between-camera-and-object-using-image)

distance_mm = object_real_world_mm * focal-length_mm / object_image_sensor_mm

Answer (score 2):

An object's apparent size within a field of view decreases linearly as it's distance from the viewer increases.  So, a circle that appears 1 inch in diameter when 5 meters from the camera will appear to be 5 inches when 1 meter from the camera.