# Multi-level object recognition using computer vision

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Are there any possible methodologies or algorithms to detect and identify multiple layers of objects (one above the other) using computer vision and image processing?
For example take a look at this image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [shittyfoodmadepretentious.com](http://www.shittyfoodmadepretentious.com/uploads/2/4/0/8/24083330/8647081_orig.jpg))</sub>

If I were to place a camera on top, will I be able to detect and identify the different layers of fruits.

Also, if not possible with computer vision, which other techniques can I possibly make use of?

Comment: what is the goal? do you want to count the fruits? what do you mean with identify the different layers?

Comment: The goal is to recognize different fruits/vegetables inside a basket using a camera installed on the top. For example, assume a fruit basket with apples at the bottom, oranges on top of it, mangoes on top of oranges. Now if i install a camera on the inside of the basket cover, it can identify and recognize mangoes as they are clearly visible, but can they recognize apples by some way?

Comment: as long as you see something of that layer and that something is sufficient to differentiate one fruit from the other you can do that. but it makes not much sense in my opinion. when I want an apple I can't pick from the top layer but from the lowest one. then the top layers collapse :) what if I want to buy 20 apples? am I supposed to remove all other fruits to get to them?

Comment: @Piglet I get what you mean. The objective of my project is to build a technology to understand fruit/vegetable rotting (through texture changes), but since the lower layers of fruits are hidden I can't monitor them. Maybe some additional sensors which can probably assist in capturing the rotting behavior of hidden fruit layers.

Comment: you can't look through the layers if that's what you want. well you could use computer tomography to do that but that's not feasable.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this purely with a camera would be very difficult since you don't have any way to know how far away the fruits are. The camera could be looking at a 2D picture of fruit and interpret it the same as a basket.

You could try complementing the camera with a range finding device, ultrasonic or radar to know how far away the fruit is in 3D space.

Another option is if you know what fruit is being observed and can approximate the actual size (diameter of the fruit irl), using similar triangles you could approximate the distance to each fruit and know their location in 3D space. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038002/opencv-how-to-calculate-distance-between-camera-and-object-using-image) question seems to have an answer that is detailed in finding distance to known object.