# OpenCV calculate distance from object with known size

Tags: opencv, math, distance

Is it possible to calculate the distance of an object with known size? 
I would like to do this with an ball which has 7cm diamater. Now for the first calculation I would put him in 30cm distance to the webcam and in the second 50cm. 
Is there a linear function or formular to calculate somehow the distance? 
Lets say in the first measure it has a diamater of 6 pixel and in the second only 4. There must be a formular for this?

Best regards

Comment: Yes, it has been explained [before here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038002/opencv-how-to-calculate-distance-between-camera-and-object-using-image)

Comment: Do I need the focal lenght? Or are there other ways without the focal lenght?

Comment: You need the focal length in mm. You can read more here using this [calculator](https://www.scantips.com/lights/subjectdistance.html). Please take time to read all the theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In optical scheme you have two similar right triangles with edges F (objective focus distance), PixelSize, Distance and Size

```
    Distance / Size = F / PixelSize
```

So having parameters for some known Distance0, you can get F (in pixel units, consider it as some constant)

```
   F = Distance0 * PixelSize0 / Size0
```

and use it to calculate unknown distance (until zoom changes)

```
  Distance = F * Size / PixelSize
```

(Note that you can vary object size)

Comment: How can you accomodate for the fact that camera is tilted at an angle ?

Comment: @Ali Waqas Camera tilt shouldn't change formula. But object image is projected onto plane normal to camera axis, so observed size can diminish

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can we somehow accomodate that angle into above formulas. 
               Distance/cos(theta) = F * Size / PixelSize
Do you think this would work. Thanks again man!

Comment: I think - yes, this should work, assuming that theta is angle between camera direction axis and object plane normal