# How to check Camera is covered or not using openCV?

Tags: opencv, video-processing

I am using open CV 3.4. I am getting feed from an RTSP input camera. I want to add a condition in my code such that if camera is covered using any thing Alert should go to user. Checking blackness of the frame doesn't do any justice because when covered with white color cloth, the frame will be white. Can anyone suggest some logic for this? How can we accomplish this using openCV?

Comment: Check if the range in color/intensity surpasses some threshold?

Comment: How can it be done by just checking color inensity , blocking with different color objects results in different result / threshold right?

Can you please send code to do so in open CV??

Comment: I don't know a direct solution for openCV but that kind of thing can be done with simple image processing techniques. You can look at the overall "range" of different pixel values (hue, saturation, lightness) and if that range is below a certain threshold the camera is covered by a lens cover, cloth(or is only capturing a pictures of a monotone colored image->wall, sky, etc.)

Comment: What is that threshold that you have to set ? camera light intensity varies accordingly at day and night ,so HSV values changes accordingly

Comment: Think of 3-4 of the most likely things a silly user might cover your camera with and record each of them into separate images or videos then analyse them to determine their characteristics. I guess the videos will be very static/unchanging if a cloth is covering the lens, also unsharp as it will be too close to focus and also have little variance if the cloth is plain.

Comment: Calculate distance between camera and object probably will work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038002/opencv-how-to-calculate-distance-between-camera-and-object-using-image and https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/

Comment: @NithinPradeep The overall change of the HSV values over a day don't matter you only need to look at range of hsv values in one picture (in certain intervals) to determine if the camera is covered. I would use all three values of HSV for "redundancy".

Comment: @gameon67 that doesn't work if for example your lens cap is on the camera.

Comment: @GittingGud does OP's camera have lens cap on? If yes, well......... use Deep Learning lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check whether the camera is in focus or not. For example, here's a blurry photo of my palm and of my window:

[image]

Here's the function that calculates a sharpness "score" of each image:

```py
def sharpness(img):
    img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    lap = cv.Laplacian(img, cv.CV_16S)
    mean, stddev = cv.meanStdDev(lap)
    return stddev[0,0]
```

Testing:

[image]

The blurry picture has a much lower score. You can set the threshold to e.g. 20 and anything below that is considered blurry and therefore the camera is covered or something else is wrong with it.

Comment: This value varies for cameras that is kept in different locations,ie for multiple cameras . so threshold varies for each.can we generalize this??

Comment: Place a Jackson Pollock painting in front of every camera. This should allow you to use the same threshold for every camera.