# Distance Measurement from PiCamera to Objects with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, object-detection, yolov5

I am very new to all this OpenCV processing. Can I measure the distance from my PiCamera v2 to any object (detected with YOLO before) with very few tolerance using OpenCV?
I heard about the mathematical formula in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038002/opencv-how-to-calculate-distance-between-camera-and-object-using-image" and the chessboard camera calibration in "https://learnopencv.com/camera-calibration-using-opencv/".
As far as I've researched, there were only examples with reference images and face detections or reference images and distance estimation of maximum two objects.

In my case I adapted the YOLO Object detection with OpenCV but also need the distances to these several objects just by using OpenCV and my PiCamera v2. Is is possible at all? Do you have any proposals?

Comment: Ye, you can . But not YOLO.

Comment: Can you show me, what I need to do? @toyotaSupra

Comment: I used rpi4 using Bullseye. I got from pyimagesearch.com. I had about 5 yrs ago.